# VBA Copy Pivot Data to next blank cell in column

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

A pivot table has been created and I need a macro that can pick up the Pivot body data, with no filters, from a specified worksheet (Pivot1) and copy the results into another sheet (Selection) on the next blank cell.

I've used and modified the below, which I found on this site, however its not picking up my sheets and I get a runtime error '424'
Any ideas on how this can be executed?

```
Sub PastePivot()

Dim i As Long
Dim LR As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim c As Long
'Find last used row in Pivot1
LR = Pivot1.Cells(Pivot1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'Find last used row in Selection
j = Selection.Cells(Selection.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'Loop through rows on Pivot1
For i = 3 To LR
    'Decide whether to copy the row or not
    If Pivot1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "0" Then
        'Update pointer to the next unused row in Selection
        j = j + 1
        'Only copy used columns, to stop it thinking every cell in the
        'destination row is "used"
        c = Pivot1.Cells(i, Pivot1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'Copy the values (without using Copy/Paste via the clipboard)
        Selection.Rows(j).Resize(1, c).Value = Pivot1.Rows(i).Resize(1, c).Value
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the body of a pivot table use it's DataBodyRange property.

The below code assumes you have 1 pivot table on 'Sheet1' and you want to copy it to 'Sheet2'.

```
Sub CopyPivotBody()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim rngBody As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables(1)
    Set rngBody = pt.DataBodyRange
    
    rngBody.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
End Sub
```

Note, if that doesn't give you the exact range you want you can offset/resize it like any other range.

Comment: This is almost perfect, and really quick. How do I get the column and row names included. Just excluding the filters at the top.

Comment: Hi, I figured it out. I just changed part of the code to "Set rngBody = pt.TableRange1" and this worked like a dream. Thanks for your help Norie.